# Number of binary search tree of height $6$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinations, trees

The number of ways in which the numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$ can be inserted in an empty binary search tree, such that the resulting tree has height $6$, is______ .

*Note*: The height of a tree with a single node is $0$.

---

My attempt :

As we need height of tree is $6$, and we have seven distinct number. Other than root node we have $2$ option at each level either node is left node or right node only.

Therefore, total number of BSTs $= 1\times2\times2\times2\times2\times2\times2 =1\times2^6=1\times64=64$ Answer.

> Can you explain in formal way or alternative way, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to go is to prove a more general property by induction.

Let $P(n)$ be: 
**The number of ways in which $n$ numbers $x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n$
can be inserted in an empty binary search tree, such that the resulting tree has height $n-1$ is $2^{n-1}$**

$P(1)$ is easy to prove.

Assume that $P(n)$ hold for some $n$ and show that $P(n+1)$ is true.
small hint:

> To do this notice that the root can only be $x_1$ or $x_{n+1}$, then apply the induction hypothesis and it should give you $P(n+1)$.

Then to prove your statement you use $P(7)$.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You get the maximum height $h=6$ with $7$ nodes, at degenerate cases, that is when the numbers inserted are in ascending or descending order. So, only the insertion orders $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$ and $(7,6,5,4,3,2,1)$ will give height $6$. So the answer is $2$.

Comment: No, your approach was my first thought, but it is wrong. Indeed, if you insert the keys in other orders, like (1,2,3,4,5,7,6)  or (1,7,2,3,4,5,6) you still obtain max height. The right answer is the other one.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry. You are right.