# Total number of possible order possible in this binary search tree?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, computer-science, binary

When searching for the key value $60$ in a binary search tree, nodes containing the key values $10, 20, 40, 50, 70, 80, 90$ are traversed, not necessarily in the order given. How many different orders are possible in which these key values can occur on the search path from the root to the node containing the value $60$?

1. $35$
2. $64$
3. $128$
4. $5040$

---

#### My attempt:

This is previous question of GATE CS/IT. This question is explained somewhere as:
There are $4$ values that are smaller than $60$ and $3$ values are greater than $60$. We can rearrange in $4! = 24$ ways smaller values and rearrange $3! = 6$ ways.
Total number of different order are $= 7! /(4!*3!) = 35$ ways.

---

My argument is:

Same as : [Number of binary search tree of height $6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659621/number-of-binary-search-tree-of-height-6)

We can have $2^4$ number of sub-trees in left of root $60$ and $2^3$ number of sub-trees in right of root $60$ (in This case, both right subtree and left sub-tree will have skewed, that means linear).
So, total number of such trees $= 2^4 \times 2^3 = 2^7 = 128$

> I am asking, what is flaw in my argument? Can you explain it, please?

Comment: Will some of these trees  not be binary search tree? Are number of total such BST different from number of order?

Comment: I don't understand your argument.  What are the "sub-trees" you are counting, exactly, and how did you get the numbers for each of them?  Can you give an example?  (I think if you actually write out what it means you may see the error yourself...)

Comment: @EricWofsey, I attempt same as this :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659621/number-of-binary-search-tree-of-height-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting something totally different from what the problem is talking about.  It appears that you are counting how many binary search trees there are that have $60$ at the top such that both branches below $60$ are linear.  But that's not at all what the binary search tree in the problem looks like.  Instead, $60$ is at the bottom, and the entire binary search tree is linear.

(Incidentally, your count is also wrong for what you are counting.  For instance, there are only $2^2$ linear binary search trees on $\{60,70,80,90\}$ that start with $60$.  There are $2^3$ linear binary search trees on this set total, but half of them start with $90$ instead of $60$.)

Comment: That means it is necessary to access all given elements before binary search returns true(i.e., element $60$ is found!). Am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but the binary search described in the problem should access all of the given numbers _before_ it reaches 60.

Comment: Thanks, I got you. Now, in your second paragraph, if root is 90, then elements I am getting 4 linear BST, i.e.,(i) 90, 80, 70, 60. (ii) 90, 80, 60, 70, (iii) 90, 60, 70, 80. (iv) 90, 60, 80, 70. So, total $2^2$ with $90$ as root element and total $2^2$ with $60$. Therefore, $2^4$ in set $\{60, 70, 80, 60\}.$. May be, you have typo?

Comment: $2^2+2^2$ is $2^3$, not $2^4$...

Comment: my bad. Thanks. So, linear BST is not possible in the set $\{10, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90\}$ with root $60$, because $\{70, 80, 90\}$ goes to right of $60$ and  $\{10, 20, 40, 50\}$ goes to left of $60$. Am I right?

Comment: That's correct.  But in this problem, $60$ is the last number you reach, not the root.

Comment: @EricWofsey sir ..thanks for your answer :) sir i am facing a bit trouble in this prblm related to BST ..https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2592713/the-number-of-ways-in-which-the-numbers-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-can-be-inserted-in-an can you please help me out ... sorry to post the link here ..but i waited for a very long time ..but could not get the answer so i posted ..sorry again :)

Answer (score 2):

A binary search tree has the property that, if a node contains value $v$, then all nodes to its left have values less than $v$, and all nodes to its right have values greater than $v$.

In this problem, a path containing all the listed values has been taken, **from the root**, to a node beneath it bearing the value $60$.

For each value $v$ appearing somewhere in the path, either:

- all subsequent values appearing in the path must be greater than $v$, or
- all subsequent values appearing in the path must be smaller than $v$.

The consequences are:

- The first value must be either $10$ or $90$.
- The next value, at any stage, must be either the smallest or greatest remaining in the list.

But the last value must be $60$. Therefore, values less than $60$ must be taken from the left-hand side, and values greater than $60$ must be taken from the right-hand side.

Therefore, the path can be represented by a permutation of the string $LLLLRRR$, and all such permutations can represent a valid path.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: Still, I am asking, what is flaw in my argument?