# The number of ways in which the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ can be inserted in an empty BST

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

### Question

> The number of ways in which the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ can be inserted in an empty binary search tree, such that the resulting tree has height $5$, is _________.

I know it is somehow similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659621/number-of-binary-search-tree-of-height-6), but i think my question will need different approach.

### My Solution/Approach

$\Rightarrow$ First Level can be filled with $1,6,7,8$

$\Rightarrow$ Second Level can be filled with $2,5,6,7$

$\Rightarrow$ Third Level can be filled with $3,4,5,6$

$\Rightarrow$ Fourth Level can be filled with $4,5,6,7$

$\Rightarrow$ Fifth Level can be filled with $5,6,7,8$

Total number of ways = $4 \times 4...\times 4  =4^{5}$

IS my answer correct ?

Comment: See whether this helps you: https://gateoverflow.in/39586/gate2016-2-40

Comment: @Rohan thanks for your reply ..  i just want to verify that My answer is correct or not ..and if it is wrong ..please provide a hint